# How to solve bad performance on runtime debugging of kotlin

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin, breakpoints

Many times I face the issues when I set breakpoints into properties which are included some class in kotlin.

All Debuggee processes are getting slower than I set the breakpoint into getter/setter methods in java.

I think this is very annoying problem for runtime debugging.

Is there any solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Slowness of debugging depends on how many variables you have added in Watches. Try to remove those watches. I experienced slowness why I added `arraylists` and `hasmaps` in watches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mustansar. but it doesn't seem to relate to my problem. All my application threads slow down when I add a watchpoint or breakpoint to any property in my project.